# Set a size for a request dialog

Tags: facebook

I'm having a bit of trouble with resizing a request dialog.

My code is this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?access_token=TOKEN&app_id=APPIDredirect_uri=MYREDIRECTURI&message=MYMESSAGE&display=iframe">
```

I'm not using FB.ui because my code already works with this kind of logic, so I just want to know how to set the dialog size, I've tried this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?access_token=TOKEN&app_id=APPIDredirect_uri=MYREDIRECTURI&message=MYMESSAGE&display=iframe&height:xxpx">
```

But it doesn't work.

Also excuse my English, my native language is Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using CSS, like:

```
<style>
.fb_dialog_content iframe { height:537px !important; }
</style>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?access_token=TOKEN&app_id=APPIDredirect_uri=MYREDIRECTURI&message=MYMESSAGE&display=iframe">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code but sadly didn't work, I tried resizing the iframe itself from the apps panel and even if it wasn't what i was looking for, it kind of works, i'm still looking how to resize it but thank you for your quick answer